# Pandas Indexing and Column Creation

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a dataset, `df`.

I extracted another dataset from `df`, `df_rec`, based on a certain condition.

I can access the indexes of `df_rec` by `df_rec.index.`

Now, I want to create a column in df, where the index in df if matches with indexes in df_rec should be populated as 1 otherwise 0.

Any help, will be appreciated.

I am thinking, like, which throws error.

```
df['reccurences'] = 0
df['reccurences'][df.index in df_rec.index] = 1
```

Comment: Post samples of the dataset and needed rsut

Comment: I am not allowed. thats just a basic operation.

Comment: what is `reccurences` .?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` on the index of `df` to chek whether it is in `df_res` and set the value accordingly as shown below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['X'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
df['Y'] = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

df_res = df.loc[df['X'] > 3]

df['C'] = df.index.map(lambda x : 1 if x in df_res.index else 0)
```

OR you can do like this

```
df['C'] = [1 if x in df_res.index else 0 for x in df.index]
```

Comment: I am looking for something like this.
df['reccurences'] = 0
df['reccurences'][df.index in df_rec.index] = 1

Comment: adding in my question

Comment: Worked, ACCPTING AFTER 3 MINUTES

Comment: DID YOU DOWNVOTED?